# how to change the background color in kendo pivot grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-grid

How do I change the background-color of the columnheader/rowHeader or grouping header in Kendo Pivot grid. I tried applying the following css in the custom.css but it is not getting affected with the grid.

These classes are originally present in the kendo.common.min.css and I want to override it my custom CSS class.

how do I change or override it?

```
.k-grouping-header k-grid-header th.k-header{
    background-color: #F7F7F7 !important;
}
```